# Verifying iframe post request from other domain

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I need to create a click to call widget(using iframe). clients will add the widget on their websites. iframe will have an input box where some customer of the client will enter their mobile number and when customer clicks on submit button a request will be made to our server directly from the customer's browser. 
How we can identify that a request was made from a valid website? Is there any way to hack this post request?
Also is there any better way?

Screenshot of widget:

[image: Click to call exmaple]

To clarify, the widget will be on other domain and post request will be sent directly to our server.

Comment: In what language? (It'l have to be server-side) PHP?

Comment: Next time remember to add it as a tag.

Answer (score 1):

The detection could be done server side. For example, with php

```
$origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

in your destination script, gives you the originating domain. You can validate with that.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Ya, but you didn't answer "Is there any way to hack this post request? Also is there any better way?"

Comment: So, answer you if you're not happy

Comment: Why? I don't have a good answer, so I'm not going to answer with a bad one.

Comment: I posted something useful to the question, may even be a partial solution. Read SO rules first.

Comment: Partial answers are not answers. They are comments.

Comment: The Op could use a captcha, to ensure legitimate human requests (not completely fool-proof though).

Comment: @bjb568 No, go read about SO q&a first, also read about microoptimization somewhere :). Bye

Comment: Why even bother? Answers are a thing said, written, or done to deal with or as a reaction to a question, statement, or situation. So, you gotta deal with the question. And you aren't.

Comment: All right: "Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative."

Comment: Post request was made from customer's browser and directly to our servers. So http_referer is not of any use.

Comment: @Ashy It depends if the form will be on your domain or their domain. If the former is true, you're right.

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado form will be on other domain.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on your server headers and specify the exact domains, to allow them to send requests from their browsers like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain1.com http://domain2.com
```

check this [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header) for more info.

the other way is to read the Origin header from the client then check it if it is one of the list of allowed domains, and if it is, write the response and set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.